# How to use foreign keys to load entities in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, postman

In regular EF, I can have the following classes created, and easily reference each other. However, this does not seem to work in EF Core - is there something different that must be done?

**Test.cs**

```
public class Test{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public IList<OtherTest> OtherTests {get;set;}
}
```

**OtherTest**

```
public class OtherTest {
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public Test Test {get;set;}
}
```

I create the initial data as follows:

```
public class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(StatusContext context)
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            if (context.ServiceGroups.Any()) return;

            var test = new Test();
            var otherTest = new OtherTest {Test = test};


            context.Tests.Add(test);
            context.OtherTests.Add(otherTest);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

**Edit**
So after scouring through various forums, I came upon the following to do in my controller:

```
//return ccontext.OtherTests;
return context.OtherTests.Include(x=>x.Test);
```

I then made the following change in Startup.cs:

```
//services.AddMvc();
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => 
options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

However, I notice the following gets returned:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "Test": {
            "id": 1,
            "OtherTests": []
        }
    }
]

I see how this can get into circular references, but what is the recommendation to ensure that I can either load the collection in the response?  Trying to tack on .ThenInclude(y=>y.OtherTests) does not seem to cut it

**Edit 2**
For what it is worth, I observed that when querying the API for Test, which contains the OtherTests list, I get the following:
[ { id: 1, otherTests: [ { id: 1} ] } ]

Note that the navigation property Test is not included above. However, when querying for OtherTest, the navigation property OtherTests is shown:

[{ id: 1, Test: { id: 1, otherTests: []} } ]

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: When I query, I get null for both Test and OtherTests properties

Comment: When you query *how*?

Comment: Using postman, this is an API.  So I just query /api/tests or /api/othertests

Comment: Consider adding the *postman* tag to your question, this might be a rather specialized area compared to C# EF in general.

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip

Comment: I think that setting `ReferenceLoopHandling` as you did is exactly what you need. Besides that, you may consider setting `PreserveReferencesHandling`.

Comment: justa hunch:  instead of .ThenInclude(y=>y.OtherTests), try .Include(y=>y.OtherTests)